# TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient without Firewall

Tags: c#, tcp, firewall

I am writing a C# application that needs to expose a REST service to a client.
In a simple setup, the client and service will run on the same computer.
In that case, I do not want to bother the user with a Firewall security alert box popping up. 
So is there a way to prevent that popup if the REST service would only accept local connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the target IP address of the TCPListener to 127.0.0.1 or IPAddress.Loopback using the following snippet.

```
 TcpListener l = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
```

This will not trigger the Windows Firewall alert since it's listening only on your local machine.